# Highchart show string on x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to show my x-axis values as a string on highcharts for a series but instead get (0,1,2....) which is the xaxis array index position. How do I show the xaxis value formatted as a string on higcharts?

Here is what I have

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with time'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
                "labels": {
                "formatter": function() {
                        console.log(this);
                        console.log(this.value.toString());
                    return this.value
                }                    
            },
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['Jan-1', 100],
      ['Jan-2', 120],
      ['Jan-3', 130]
    ]
  }]
});
```

Would like to see 'Jan-1', 'Jan-2' as the labels on the x-axis. Here is a link to the fiddle below https://jsfiddle.net/dLfv2sbd/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove `labels` and use `type: 'category'` instead of `type: 'datetime'`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with time'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['Jan-1', 100],
      ['Jan-2', 120],
      ['Jan-3', 130]
    ]
  }]
});
```

Check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7v5Lh826/).

Comment: Thanks this is  what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can still use datetime this way.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Chart with time'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
                "labels": {
                "formatter": function() {
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%e', this.value)
                }                    
            },
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2017,0,1), 100],
      [Date.UTC(2017,0,2), 120],
      [Date.UTC(2017,0,3), 130]
    ]
  }]
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dLfv2sbd/4/

Comment: Interesting I will check this out