# Form data series for highcharts columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts

From the official documentation I can't get if it is possible for me to build a chart in the way I want.

Simple example of the initial data:

```
{
  'Player1': {'item1': '50'},
  'Player2': {'item1': '60', 'item2': '20'},
  'Player3': {'item3': '40'}
}
```

It is like the 3 dimensions: `Players/Items/Values`.
I would like to build a chart with the `column` type.
`X-Axis` for the `PlayerNames` and `Y-Axis` for the `Values`.
The `Items` might be like the `series-names` so I can select them one by one and switch their `visible` option.

The issues - is that I don't get how to properly build the `series` and is that possible to bind their values between `X-Y`:

```
series: [{
        name: 'item1',
        data: [{x: 'Player1', y: 50}, {x: 'Player2', y: 60}],
        visible: false
    },
    {
        name: 'item2',
        data: [{x: 'Player2', y: 20}],
        visible: false
    },
    {
        name: 'item3',
        data: [{x: 'Player3', y: 40}],
        visible: false
    }
]
```

This would let me to show on the X-Axis only the colums that actually have the data. Without the empty space.
Can I achieve this somehow?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to find the way how to do it:

First of all I should mention that `x` works only for the numbers:
[x: number](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data.x)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683114/highchart-show-string-on-x-axis) is the way how to do it for string values:

```
xAxis: {
   type: 'category',
},
```

And then just as:

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'item1',
            data: [['Player1', 50], ['Player2', 75]],
            visible: true
        },
        {
            name: 'item2',
            data: [['Player1', 25], ['Player3', 60], ['Player4', 40]],
            visible: false
        }
    ],
```